# Estimate $\|D^2u\|_{L^\infty}$ for solution $u$ to Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I'm looking for an upper bound on $\|\partial_{ij} u\|_{L^\infty}$, where $u$ is the solution to
$$
\Delta u = -1 \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega,\\
u = 0 \quad \text{on} \quad \partial\Omega.
$$
The upper bound may depend on the diameter of $\Omega$, but not on other properties of $\Omega$.

I think the question may have something to do with "Schauder estimates" but I'm struggling to make sense of them. Would be grateful for pointers to easy-to-read resources on this topic.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf) help you? Especially equation (2.10) looks somewhat similar to what you are interested.

Comment: Yes you can get this from Schauder estimates. The Schauder estimates for $-\Delta u=f$ in $\Omega$ say for each $\Omega’ \subset \subset \Omega$, $\| u\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega’)} \leqslant C(\| u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} + \| f\|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)})$

Comment: Then using $f=1$ and that $\| u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leqslant C (\mathrm{diam}(\Omega))^2$ you get what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R= \mathrm{diam} \,(\Omega)$ and, after possibly translating $\Omega$, we can assume that that $\Omega \subset B_R$. Let $v = u -\frac1 {2n}(R^2- \vert x \vert^2 )$. Then $$\Delta v=0 \qquad \text{in } \Omega.$$ By the Cauchy estimates, for each $\Omega'\subset \subset \Omega$, $$\| D^2 v \|_{L^\infty(\Omega')} \leqslant C \| v \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \tag{$\ast$}$$ where $C=C(n,\mathrm{diam} (\Omega'),\mathrm{dist}\,(\partial \Omega,\Omega'))>0.$ Since $D_{ij}v=D_{ij}u+\frac 1 n \delta_{ij}$, it follows from $(\ast)$ that $$\| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega')} \leqslant C \big ( \| u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} +1 \big ). \tag{$\ast\ast$}$$

Now let us estimate $\| u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$. Since $u$ is superharmonic and zero on $\partial \Omega$ the comparison principles says that $u\geqslant 0$. Moreover, $v$ is harmonic and $v\leqslant 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, so the comparison principle tells us that $v\leqslant 0$ in $\Omega$, that is, $$u\leqslant \frac1 {2n}(R^2- \vert x \vert^2 )\leqslant \frac 1 {2n} (\mathrm {diam} \,\Omega)^2. $$ Thus, combining this with $(\ast\ast)$, we have that for each $\Omega'\subset \subset \Omega$ $$\| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega')} \leqslant C (\mathrm {diam}\, \Omega)^2. $$

Note: If you would like estimates up to the boundary then we need information about the regularity of the boundary of $\Omega$.

Edit: To answer you question in the comments about the constant in the Cauchy estimate. I don't know of a specific textbook which has exactly what you are looking for (often they just say $C$ depends on $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$). Here's what I was thinking: The standard Cauchy estimates say that $$ \| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(B_r(x))} \leqslant \frac{C}{r^{n+2}}\|u\|_{L^1(B_r(x))}\leqslant\frac{C}{r^2}\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_r(x))}$$ for each $B_r(x) \subset \Omega$ and $C=C(n)$. By compactness of $\Omega'$ in $\Omega$, let $N$ be the smallest integer such that there exists $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^N\subset \Omega'$ such that $$ \Omega'\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N B_r(x_j)$$ where $r=\mathrm{dist}\,(\partial \Omega,\Omega')/2$. Note that we have that the right hand side is a subset of $\Omega$ by our choice of $r$. Then $$\| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(\Omega')} \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^N\| D^2 u \|_{L^\infty(B_r(x))}\leqslant \frac C {r^2}\sum_{j=1}^N\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_r(x))}\leqslant \frac C {r^2}N\|u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}.$$ To estimate $N$ note that $\Omega' \subset B_{\mathrm{diam}(\Omega')/2}(x)$ for any $x\in \Omega'$ and that $B_{\mathrm{diam}(\Omega')/2}(x)$ can be covered with $\approx \mathrm{diam}(\Omega')^n / \mathrm{dist}\,(\partial \Omega,\Omega')^n$ (you would need to make this rigorous) balls of radius $\mathrm{dist}\,(\partial \Omega,\Omega')/2$. Hence, you should get $N \leqslant C\mathrm{diam}(\Omega')^n / \mathrm{dist}\,(\partial \Omega,\Omega')^n$ for some universal constant $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this gets me most of the way.
My plan was to use $\|D^2 u\|_{L^\infty}$ to bound $\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty}$ by the radius of the greatest inscribed circle of the domain (times a constant that only depends on the diameter of $\Omega$). But I probably need an estimate up to the boundary (which I may assume to be $C^\infty$) to do this.
One more thing: How do I get $(\ast)$ from Cauchy's estimate for harmonic functions? And how do I see that $C$ only depend on the diameter of $\Omega'$, but not on the shape of $\Omega$ itself? Could you point me to a reference?

Comment: Shouldn't the constant $C$ in ($\ast$) depend on $\mathrm{dist}(\Omega',\partial\Omega)$ instead of the diameter of $\Omega'$? This arises when you take suitable cutoffs, and otherwise you would be able to take $\Omega'_n$ which increase to $\Omega$ and pass to the limit in the estimate.

Comment: @ktoi Yes I agree

Comment: @chafner If you want estimates up to the boundary then you should probably use Schauder estimates. To do it directly like I've done above for the interior case you'll have to flatten the boundary etc